# SetFilePointer with start point is at EOF

Tags: winapi, pinvoke, windows-ce

Trying to increase file writing performance on the old MC3090 device (Windows CE 5.0) I went to WinAPI calls. I have to open file and append data several times, so every time I create filehandle with `CreateFile` function, then seek to the end, and write data.
The problem is that winapi doesn't want to seek to the end.

Here is my test example.

Constants:

```
private const uint GENERIC_WRITE = 0x40000000;
private const uint OPEN_ALWAYS = 4;
private const uint EMOVE_METHOD_END = 2;
```

Functions import:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("coredll.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern unsafe IntPtr CreateFile
(
    string FileName,          // file name
    uint DesiredAccess,       // access mode
    uint ShareMode,           // share mode
    uint SecurityAttributes,  // Security Attributes
    uint CreationDisposition, // how to create
    uint FlagsAndAttributes,  // file attributes
    int hTemplateFile         // handle to template file
);
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("coredll.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern unsafe bool WriteFile
(
    IntPtr handle,             // handle to file
    void* pBuffer,             // data buffer
    int NumberOfBytesToWrite,  // Number of bytes to write.
    int* pNumberOfBytesWritten,// Number of bytes that were written..
    int Overlapped             // Overlapped buffer which is used for async I/O.  Not used here.
);
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("coredll.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern unsafe uint SetFilePointer
(
   IntPtr hFile,
   long lDistanceToMove,
   int* lpDistanceToMoveHigh,
   uint dwMoveMethod
);
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("coredll.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern unsafe bool CloseHandle
(
   System.IntPtr hObject
);
```

Console program `Main` method:

```
    static unsafe void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (File.Exists("\\storage card\\native.bin"))
            File.Delete("\\storage card\\native.bin");
        var random = new Random();
        var i = 0;
        while (i++ < 3)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Iteration #" + i);
            var buf = new byte[500000];
            random.NextBytes(buf);

            var gchBuf = GCHandle.Alloc(buf, GCHandleType.Pinned);
            gchBuf.AddrOfPinnedObject();
            var pbuf = gchBuf.AddrOfPinnedObject().ToPointer();

            var pHandle = CreateFile("\\storage card\\native.bin", GENERIC_WRITE, 0, 0, OPEN_ALWAYS, 0, 0);
            Console.WriteLine("Open Error - " + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

            var newpos = SetFilePointer(pHandle, 0, null, EMOVE_METHOD_END);

            Console.WriteLine("New position - " + newpos);
            Console.WriteLine("Pos Error - " + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

            int numberOfBytesWritten;
            WriteFile(pHandle, pbuf, 500000, &numberOfBytesWritten, 0);

            Console.WriteLine("Written - " + numberOfBytesWritten);
            Console.WriteLine("Write Error - " + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());

            CloseHandle(pHandle);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Console output:

```
Iteration #1
Open Error - 2       // ?????
New position - 0
Pos Error - 0
Written - 500000
Write Error - 87      // ?
Result file size - 500000
Iteration #2
Open Error - 183
New position - 0
Pos Error - 0
Written - 500000
Write Error - 50      // ?
Result file size - 500000
Iteration #3
Open Error - 183
New position - 0
Pos Error - 0
Written - 500000
Write Error - 50      // ?
Result file size - 500000
```

Any iteration after the third will be the same.
So, I don't understand the following effects:

1. First CreateFile call returns 2 (ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND). After @RemyLebeau comment I expect code 0.
2. WriteFile calls result ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED and ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER, but file become written. Further, I can check it's content, and it equals to buffer content.
3. SetFilePointer doesn't fail but doesn't change position.

Comment: You should provide a complete program the demonstrates the problem

Comment: After `CreateFile()` exits, does `GetLastError()` report 0 (a new file was created) or 183 (an existing file was opened)?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, thanks, updated an example

Comment: @RemyLebeau, thanks, updated an example

Comment: I'm sorry, I've just tangled a lot. Problem of this example code was similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/12949937/3237954 . My real program's code haven't this problem, so problem is some another...

Comment: You are not checking for errors. Start by doing that. Check return values of api calls.

Comment: I don't understand why you use unsafe here. hTemplate and lpOverlapped should be IntPtr. Code would be a lot easier if you used SetFilePointerEx. Finally, none of this will give you a performance boost.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, thanks for your attention. I use unsafe cause took this code [here](http://designingefficientsoftware.wordpress.com/2011/03/03/efficient-file-io-from-csharp/). I transmit a zero as `hTemplate` and `lpOverlapped`, i think it equals to `IntPtr.Zero`. There's [no](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa516939.aspx) `SetFilePointerEx` in the WinCE5. Anyway, I haven't any problem with this test app (see comment #5). I would mark this question as duplicate.

Comment: `GetLastError()` is only meaningful when a function fails, or when a function is specifically documented as using `GetLastError()` on success to report additional info. On that last part,  `CreateFile()` does, but `WriteFile()` and `SetFilePointer()` do not.

Comment: `WriteFile()` failed with `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER` when `CreateFile()` failed with `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`, but you are not checking for that failure. Everything was fine when `CreateFile()` succeeded, you were simply calling `GetLastError()` when you should not have been calling it. I don't know why `newpos` is always 0 when `CreateFile()` successfully opens an existing file, it should not be unless the file is empty.